# Python: Slicing 2d NumPy array to produce order C arrays while using Numba

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I've started using Numba and right now I'm trying speed up an algorithm using Numba. However, I'm having trouble with a numpy.dot operation. The problem is when I slice a 2d array of strings column-by-column it produces an array of type array([unichr x 100], 1d, A). I need this type to be array([unichr x 100], 1d, C) in order for the numpy.where to produce an array of type array(float64, 1d, C). This array is then used in the numpy.dot operation with another array of the same type. Numba is telling me that I doesn't like the fact that the arrays have different orders, A and C. The algorithm works fine without Numba.

Here is a short example to illustrate the problem.

```
data_X = [['a1','b2','c1'],
          ['a1','b2','c2'],
          ['a2','b1','c3'],
          ['a1','b2','c1'],
          ['a2','b1','c3']]
data_Y = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
X = np.array(data_X, dtype='<U100')
Y = np.array(data_Y, dtype=np.float64)

@nb.jit(
    nopython=True,
    locals={
        'X': nb.types.Array(nb.types.UnicodeCharSeq(100), 2, 'C'),
        'Y': nb.types.Array(nb.float64, 1, 'C'),
    }
)
def func(X, Y):
    results = []
    for i in range(X.shape[1]):
        uniqs = np.unique(X[:,i])
        for u in uniqs:
            X_vars = np.where(X[:,i] == np.full_like(X[:,i], u), 1.0, 0.0)
            results.append(np.dot(X_vars, Y))
    return results

func(X, Y)
```

The answer I get without Numba is [7.0, 8.0, 8.0, 7.0, 5.0, 2.0, 8.0]. With Numba I get the following error:

```
<ipython-input-27-42fe2e73a7cd>:23: NumbaPerformanceWarning: np.dot() is faster on contiguous arrays, called on (array(float64, 1d, A), array(float64, 1d, C))
  results.append(np.dot(X_vars, Y))
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\DataScience\lib\site-packages\numba\core\errors.py", line 745, in new_error_context
    yield

  File "C:\DataScience\lib\site-packages\numba\core\lowering.py", line 273, in lower_block
    self.lower_inst(inst)

  File "C:\DataScience\lib\site-packages\numba\core\lowering.py", line 370, in lower_inst
    val = self.lower_assign(ty, inst)

  File "C:\DataScience\lib\site-packages\numba\core\lowering.py", line 544, in lower_assign
    return self.lower_expr(ty, value)

  File "C:\DataScience\lib\site-packages\numba\core\lowering.py", line 1266, in lower_expr
    res = self.context.special_ops[expr.op](self, expr)

  File "C:\DataScience\lib\site-packages\numba\np\ufunc\array_exprs.py", line 397, in _lower_array_expr
    context, builder, outer_sig, args, ExprKernel, explicit_output=False)

  File "C:\DataScience\lib\site-packages\numba\np\npyimpl.py", line 327, in numpy_ufunc_kernel
    output = _build_array(context, builder, ret_ty, sig.args, arguments)

  File "C:\DataScience\lib\site-packages\numba\np\npyimpl.py", line 281, in _build_array
    dest_shape_tup)

  File "C:\DataScience\lib\site-packages\numba\np\arrayobj.py", line 3385, in _empty_nd_impl
    arrtype.layout))

NotImplementedError: Don't know how to allocate array with layout 'A'.


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-27-42fe2e73a7cd>", line 26, in <module>
    func(X, Y)

  File "C:\DataScience\lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py", line 434, in _compile_for_args
    raise e

  File "C:\DataScience\lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py", line 367, in _compile_for_args
    return self.compile(tuple(argtypes))

  File "C:\DataScience\lib\site-packages\numba\core\compiler_lock.py", line 32, in _acquire_compile_lock
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\DataScience\lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py", line 808, in compile
    cres = self._compiler.compile(args, return_type)

  File "C:\DataScience\lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py", line 78, in compile
    status, retval = self._compile_cached(args, return_type)

  File "C:\DataScience\lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py", line 92, in _compile_cached
    retval = self._compile_core(args, return_type)

  File "C:\DataScience\lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py", line 110, in _compile_core
    pipeline_class=self.pipeline_class)

  File "C:\DataScience\lib\site-packages\numba\core\compiler.py", line 603, in compile_extra
    return pipeline.compile_extra(func)

  File "C:\DataScience\lib\site-packages\numba\core\compiler.py", line 339, in compile_extra
    return self._compile_bytecode()

  File "C:\DataScience\lib\site-packages\numba\core\compiler.py", line 401, in _compile_bytecode
    return self._compile_core()

  File "C:\DataScience\lib\site-packages\numba\core\compiler.py", line 381, in _compile_core
    raise e

  File "C:\DataScience\lib\site-packages\numba\core\compiler.py", line 372, in _compile_core
    pm.run(self.state)

  File "C:\DataScience\lib\site-packages\numba\core\compiler_machinery.py", line 341, in run
    raise patched_exception

  File "C:\DataScience\lib\site-packages\numba\core\compiler_machinery.py", line 332, in run
    self._runPass(idx, pass_inst, state)

  File "C:\DataScience\lib\site-packages\numba\core\compiler_lock.py", line 32, in _acquire_compile_lock
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\DataScience\lib\site-packages\numba\core\compiler_machinery.py", line 291, in _runPass
    mutated |= check(pss.run_pass, internal_state)

  File "C:\DataScience\lib\site-packages\numba\core\compiler_machinery.py", line 264, in check
    mangled = func(compiler_state)

  File "C:\DataScience\lib\site-packages\numba\core\typed_passes.py", line 442, in run_pass
    NativeLowering().run_pass(state)

  File "C:\DataScience\lib\site-packages\numba\core\typed_passes.py", line 370, in run_pass
    lower.lower()

  File "C:\DataScience\lib\site-packages\numba\core\lowering.py", line 179, in lower
    self.lower_normal_function(self.fndesc)

  File "C:\DataScience\lib\site-packages\numba\core\lowering.py", line 233, in lower_normal_function
    entry_block_tail = self.lower_function_body()

  File "C:\DataScience\lib\site-packages\numba\core\lowering.py", line 259, in lower_function_body
    self.lower_block(block)

  File "C:\DataScience\lib\site-packages\numba\core\lowering.py", line 273, in lower_block
    self.lower_inst(inst)

  File "C:\DataScience\lib\contextlib.py", line 130, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)

  File "C:\DataScience\lib\site-packages\numba\core\errors.py", line 752, in new_error_context
    reraise(type(newerr), newerr, tb)

  File "C:\DataScience\lib\site-packages\numba\core\utils.py", line 81, in reraise
    raise value

LoweringError: Don't know how to allocate array with layout 'A'.
```

Comment: `numba` isn't as flexible on these kinds of things as `numpy`.  That's the price of greater speed.  But I suspect you can do this task in more basic code without the `where` or the `dot`. `Y` is 1d so the dot is a simple 1d iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, let's figure out where exactly numba is facing trouble. If we simplify the operations down to:

```
def func(X, Y):
    #results = []
    for i in range(X.shape[1]):
        uniqs = np.unique(X[:,i])
        for u in uniqs:
            X_vars = (X[:,i] == np.full_like(X[:,i], u))
            #X_vars = np.where(X[:,i] == np.full_like(X[:,i], u), 1.0, 0.0)
            #results.append(np.dot(X_vars, Y))
    #return results
```

Then numba still continues to throw the same error: `NotImplementedError: Don't know how to allocate array with layout 'A'`. So this is where the problem is. In fact, you can reproduce the same error with an even simpler operation:

```
def func(X, Y):
    for i in range(X.shape[1]):
        X[:,i] == X[:,i]
```

The stack trace provides a hint: the problem is in contiguity. Here, `X[:,i]` is a view and thus does not have 'C'/'F' contiguity specified, making numba go nuts. So a simple solution would be to add an extra line and apply `np.ascontiguousarray` on your view. A deep copy would also work just as well.

```
@nb.jit(
    nopython=True,
    locals={
        'X': nb.types.Array(nb.types.UnicodeCharSeq(100), 2, 'C'),
        'Y': nb.types.Array(nb.float64, 1, 'C'),
    }
)
def func(X, Y):
    results = []
    for i in range(X.shape[1]):
        X_i = np.ascontiguousarray(X[:,i])
        uniqs = np.unique(X_i)
        for u in uniqs:
            X_vars = np.where( X_i == np.full_like(X_i, u), 1.0, 0.0)
            results.append(np.dot(X_vars, Y))
    return results
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution, it certainly has made my code functional. Unfortunately, it appears that it is slower than the same Python code without the Numba decorator. Timeit results:- without Numba: 82.1 µs ± 650 ns per loop, with Numba: 600 µs ± 17.8 µs per loop. Numba gets even slower when I scale up the problem. Seems I'll have to find a different approach, but your answer is still appreciated.

Comment: Setting cache=True isn't changing run time doesn't seems to change the runtime of the code.