# AlphaPeel: numba fails to allocate array with layout A

Tags: python, arrays, floating-point, numba

I try to use [AlphaPeel](https://github.com/AlphaGenes/AlphaPeel) for some [hybrid peeling](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/30563452/).  I followed the tools doc to create genotype.txt and pedigree.txt format as specified input.
From AlphaPeel doc:

> Genotype file
>
> Genotype files contain the input genotypes for each
> individual. The first value in each line is the individual’s id. The
> remaining values are the genotypes of the individual at each locus,
> either 0, 1, or 2 (or 9 if missing). Example:
>
> ```
> id1 1 1 2 0 1 1 1 1 1 0
> id2 0 2 1 1 0 1 1 1 2 2
> id3 1 2 0 1 2 1 0 1 2 0
> id4 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1
> ```
>
> Pedigree file
>
> Each line of a pedigree file has three values, the
> individual’s id, their father’s id, and their mother’s id. "0"
> represents an unknown id. Example:
>
> ```
> id1 0 0
> id2 0 0
> id3 id1 id2
> id4 id1 id2
> ```

But when I try to call AlphaPeel with :`AlphaPeel -genotypes genotype.txt -pedigree pedigree.txt -runtype='multi' -out 1kg_22_seq`

I recieve the following output :

```
Reading in AlphaImpute Format: genotype.txt
Cycle  0
Peeling Down, Generation 0
Peeling Down, Generation 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/oem/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/errors.py", line 823, in new_error_context
    yield
  File "/home/oem/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/lowering.py", line 265, in lower_block
    self.lower_inst(inst)
  File "/home/oem/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/lowering.py", line 439, in lower_inst
    val = self.lower_assign(ty, inst)
  File "/home/oem/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/lowering.py", line 626, in lower_assign
    return self.lower_expr(ty, value)
  File "/home/oem/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/lowering.py", line 1368, in lower_expr
    res = self.context.special_ops[expr.op](self, expr)
  File "/home/oem/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/np/ufunc/array_exprs.py", line 405, in _lower_array_expr
    return npyimpl.numpy_ufunc_kernel(
  File "/home/oem/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/np/npyimpl.py", line 360, in numpy_ufunc_kernel
    output = _build_array(context, builder, ret_ty, sig.args, arguments)
  File "/home/oem/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/np/npyimpl.py", line 286, in _build_array
    array_val = arrayobj._empty_nd_impl(context, builder, real_array_ty,
  File "/home/oem/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/np/arrayobj.py", line 3923, in _empty_nd_impl
    raise NotImplementedError(
NotImplementedError: Don't know how to allocate array with layout 'A'.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/oem/anaconda3/bin/AlphaPeel", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('AlphaPeel==1.1.0', 'console_scripts', 'AlphaPeel')())
  File "/home/oem/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tinypeel/tinypeel.py", line 191, in main
    runPeelingCycles(pedigree, peelingInfo, args, singleLocusMode = singleLocusMode)
  File "/home/oem/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tinypeel/tinypeel.py", line 23, in runPeelingCycles
    peelingCycle(pedigree, peelingInfo, args = args, singleLocusMode = singleLocusMode)
  File "/home/oem/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tinypeel/tinypeel.py", line 46, in peelingCycle
    Peeling.peel(family, Peeling.PEEL_DOWN, peelingInfo, singleLocusMode)
  File "/home/oem/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/dispatcher.py", line 487, in _compile_for_args
    raise e
  File "/home/oem/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/dispatcher.py", line 420, in _compile_for_args
    return_val = self.compile(tuple(argtypes))
  File "/home/oem/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/dispatcher.py", line 965, in compile
    cres = self._compiler.compile(args, return_type)
  File "/home/oem/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/dispatcher.py", line 125, in compile
    status, retval = self._compile_cached(args, return_type)
  File "/home/oem/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/dispatcher.py", line 139, in _compile_cached
    retval = self._compile_core(args, return_type)
  File "/home/oem/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/dispatcher.py", line 152, in _compile_core
    cres = compiler.compile_extra(self.targetdescr.typing_context,
  File "/home/oem/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/compiler.py", line 716, in compile_extra
    return pipeline.compile_extra(func)
  File "/home/oem/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/compiler.py", line 452, in compile_extra
    return self._compile_bytecode()
  File "/home/oem/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/compiler.py", line 520, in _compile_bytecode
    return self._compile_core()
  File "/home/oem/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/compiler.py", line 499, in _compile_core
    raise e
  File "/home/oem/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/compiler.py", line 486, in _compile_core
    pm.run(self.state)
  File "/home/oem/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/compiler_machinery.py", line 368, in run
    raise patched_exception
  File "/home/oem/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/compiler_machinery.py", line 356, in run
    self._runPass(idx, pass_inst, state)
  File "/home/oem/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/compiler_lock.py", line 35, in _acquire_compile_lock
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/oem/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/compiler_machinery.py", line 311, in _runPass
    mutated |= check(pss.run_pass, internal_state)
  File "/home/oem/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/compiler_machinery.py", line 273, in check
    mangled = func(compiler_state)
  File "/home/oem/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/typed_passes.py", line 394, in run_pass
    lower.lower()
  File "/home/oem/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/lowering.py", line 168, in lower
    self.lower_normal_function(self.fndesc)
  File "/home/oem/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/lowering.py", line 222, in lower_normal_function
    entry_block_tail = self.lower_function_body()
  File "/home/oem/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/lowering.py", line 251, in lower_function_body
    self.lower_block(block)
  File "/home/oem/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/lowering.py", line 265, in lower_block
    self.lower_inst(inst)
  File "/home/oem/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/contextlib.py", line 137, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(typ, value, traceback)
  File "/home/oem/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/errors.py", line 837, in new_error_context
    raise newerr.with_traceback(tb)
numba.core.errors.LoweringError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: native lowering)
Don't know how to allocate array with layout 'A'.

File "../../anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tinypeel/Peeling/Peeling.py", line 86:
def peel(family, operation, peelingInfo, singleLocusMode) :
    <source elided>
        # We are estimating the parent's genotypes so the anterior term is ignored to avoid double counting.
        childValues = posterior[child,:,:] * penetrance[child,:,:]
        ^

During: lowering "childValues = arrayexpr(expr=(<built-in function mul>, [Var($530binary_subscr.17, Peeling.py:86), Var($550binary_subscr.29, Peeling.py:86)]), ty=array(float32, 2d, A))" at /home/oem/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tinypeel/Peeling/Peeling.py (86)
```

My `genotype.txt` file contains 4 samples with 1603397 columns on each line.
My best guess here is that this might be due to the way`numba` handles floats for faster computation. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64044846/python-slicing-2d-numpy-array-to-produce-order-c-arrays-while-using-numba) for a related question.

My python version is : `python --version Python 3.9.12` and `numba 0.56.4`
My python packages list :

```
aiohttp                       3.8.1
aiosignal                     1.2.0
alabaster                     0.7.12
AlphaPeel                     1.0.0
anaconda-client               1.9.0
anaconda-navigator            2.1.4
anaconda-project              0.10.2
anyio                         3.5.0
appdirs                       1.4.4
argon2-cffi                   21.3.0
argon2-cffi-bindings          21.2.0
arrow                         1.2.2
astroid                       2.6.6
astropy                       5.0.4
asttokens                     2.0.5
async-timeout                 4.0.1
atomicwrites                  1.4.0
attrs                         21.4.0
Automat                       20.2.0
autopep8                      1.6.0
Babel                         2.9.1
backcall                      0.2.0
backports.functools-lru-cache 1.6.4
backports.tempfile            1.0
backports.weakref             1.0.post1
bcrypt                        3.2.0
beautifulsoup4                4.11.1
binaryornot                   0.4.4
bio                           1.4.0
biopython                     1.79
biothings-client              0.2.6
bitarray                      2.4.1
bkcharts                      0.2
black                         19.10b0
bleach                        4.1.0
bokeh                         2.4.2
boto3                         1.21.32
botocore                      1.24.32
Bottleneck                    1.3.4
brotlipy                      0.7.0
cachetools                    4.2.2
certifi                       2021.10.8
cffi                          1.15.0
chardet                       4.0.0
charset-normalizer            2.0.4
click                         8.0.4
cloudpickle                   2.0.0
clyent                        1.2.2
colorama                      0.4.4
colorcet                      2.0.6
conda                         4.12.0
conda-build                   3.21.8
conda-content-trust           0+unknown
conda-pack                    0.6.0
conda-package-handling        1.8.1
conda-repo-cli                1.0.4
conda-token                   0.3.0
conda-verify                  3.4.2
constantly                    15.1.0
cookiecutter                  1.7.3
cryptography                  3.4.8
cssselect                     1.1.0
cycler                        0.11.0
Cython                        0.29.28
cytoolz                       0.11.0
daal4py                       2021.5.0
dask                          2022.2.1
datashader                    0.13.0
datashape                     0.5.4
debugpy                       1.5.1
decorator                     5.1.1
defusedxml                    0.7.1
diff-match-patch              20200713
distributed                   2022.2.1
docutils                      0.17.1
entrypoints                   0.4
et-xmlfile                    1.1.0
executing                     0.8.3
fastjsonschema                2.15.1
filelock                      3.6.0
flake8                        3.9.2
Flask                         1.1.2
fonttools                     4.25.0
frozenlist                    1.2.0
fsspec                        2022.2.0
future                        0.18.2
gensim                        4.1.2
glob2                         0.7
gmpy2                         2.1.2
google-api-core               1.25.1
google-auth                   1.33.0
google-cloud-core             1.7.1
google-cloud-storage          1.31.0
google-crc32c                 1.1.2
google-resumable-media        1.3.1
googleapis-common-protos      1.53.0
greenlet                      1.1.1
grpcio                        1.42.0
h5py                          3.6.0
HeapDict                      1.0.1
holoviews                     1.14.8
hvplot                        0.7.3
hyperlink                     21.0.0
idna                          3.3
imagecodecs                   2021.8.26
imageio                       2.9.0
imagesize                     1.3.0
importlib-metadata            4.11.3
incremental                   21.3.0
inflection                    0.5.1
iniconfig                     1.1.1
intake                        0.6.5
intervaltree                  3.1.0
ipykernel                     6.9.1
ipython                       8.2.0
ipython-genutils              0.2.0
ipywidgets                    7.6.5
isal                          1.1.0
isort                         5.9.3
itemadapter                   0.3.0
itemloaders                   1.0.4
itsdangerous                  2.0.1
jdcal                         1.4.1
jedi                          0.18.1
jeepney                       0.7.1
Jinja2                        2.11.3
jinja2-time                   0.2.0
jmespath                      0.10.0
joblib                        1.1.0
json5                         0.9.6
jsonschema                    4.4.0
jupyter                       1.0.0
jupyter-client                6.1.12
jupyter-console               6.4.0
jupyter-core                  4.9.2
jupyter-server                1.13.5
jupyterlab                    3.3.2
jupyterlab-pygments           0.1.2
jupyterlab-server             2.10.3
jupyterlab-widgets            1.0.0
keyring                       23.4.0
kiwisolver                    1.3.2
lazy-object-proxy             1.6.0
libarchive-c                  2.9
llvmlite                      0.39.1
locket                        0.2.1
lxml                          4.8.0
Markdown                      3.3.4
MarkupSafe                    2.0.1
matplotlib                    3.5.1
matplotlib-inline             0.1.2
mccabe                        0.6.1
mistune                       0.8.4
mkl-fft                       1.3.1
mkl-random                    1.2.2
mkl-service                   2.4.0
mock                          4.0.3
mpmath                        1.2.1
msgpack                       1.0.2
multidict                     5.2.0
multipledispatch              0.6.0
munkres                       1.1.4
mygene                        3.2.2
mypy-extensions               0.4.3
navigator-updater             0.2.1
nbclassic                     0.3.5
nbclient                      0.5.13
nbconvert                     6.4.4
nbformat                      5.3.0
nest-asyncio                  1.5.5
networkx                      2.7.1
nltk                          3.7
nose                          1.3.7
notebook                      6.4.8
numba                         0.56.4
numexpr                       2.8.1
numpy                         1.21.5
numpydoc                      1.2
olefile                       0.46
openpyxl                      3.0.9
packaging                     21.3
pandas                        1.4.2
pandocfilters                 1.5.0
panel                         0.13.0
param                         1.12.0
parsel                        1.6.0
parso                         0.8.3
partd                         1.2.0
pathspec                      0.7.0
patsy                         0.5.2
pep8                          1.7.1
pexpect                       4.8.0
pickleshare                   0.7.5
Pillow                        9.0.1
pip                           21.2.4
pkginfo                       1.8.2
plotly                        5.6.0
pluggy                        1.0.0
poyo                          0.5.0
prometheus-client             0.13.1
prompt-toolkit                3.0.20
Protego                       0.1.16
protobuf                      3.19.1
psutil                        5.8.0
ptyprocess                    0.7.0
pure-eval                     0.2.2
py                            1.11.0
pyasn1                        0.4.8
pyasn1-modules                0.2.8
pycodestyle                   2.7.0
pycosat                       0.6.3
pycparser                     2.21
pyct                          0.4.6
pycurl                        7.44.1
PyDispatcher                  2.0.5
pydocstyle                    6.1.1
pyerfa                        2.0.0
pyfaidx                       0.7.1
pyflakes                      2.3.1
Pygments                      2.11.2
PyHamcrest                    2.0.2
PyJWT                         2.1.0
pylint                        2.9.6
pyls-spyder                   0.4.0
pyodbc                        4.0.32
pyOpenSSL                     21.0.0
pyparsing                     3.0.4
pyrsistent                    0.18.0
pysam                         0.19.1
PySocks                       1.7.1
pytest                        7.1.1
python-dateutil               2.8.2
python-lsp-black              1.0.0
python-lsp-jsonrpc            1.0.0
python-lsp-server             1.2.4
python-slugify                5.0.2
python-snappy                 0.6.0
pytz                          2021.3
pyviz-comms                   2.0.2
PyWavelets                    1.3.0
pyxdg                         0.27
PyYAML                        6.0
pyzmq                         22.3.0
QDarkStyle                    3.0.2
qstylizer                     0.1.10
QtAwesome                     1.0.3
qtconsole                     5.3.0
QtPy                          2.0.1
queuelib                      1.5.0
regex                         2022.3.15
requests                      2.27.1
requests-file                 1.5.1
rope                          0.22.0
rsa                           4.7.2
Rtree                         0.9.7
ruamel-yaml-conda             0.15.100
s3transfer                    0.5.0
scikit-image                  0.19.2
scikit-learn                  1.0.2
scikit-learn-intelex          2021.20220215.212715
scipy                         1.7.3
Scrapy                        2.6.1
seaborn                       0.11.2
SecretStorage                 3.3.1
Send2Trash                    1.8.0
service-identity              18.1.0
setuptools                    61.2.0
sip                           4.19.13
six                           1.16.0
smart-open                    5.1.0
sniffio                       1.2.0
snowballstemmer               2.2.0
sortedcollections             2.1.0
sortedcontainers              2.4.0
soupsieve                     2.3.1
Sphinx                        4.4.0
sphinxcontrib-applehelp       1.0.2
sphinxcontrib-devhelp         1.0.2
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp        2.0.0
sphinxcontrib-jsmath          1.0.1
sphinxcontrib-qthelp          1.0.3
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml 1.1.5
spyder                        5.1.5
spyder-kernels                2.1.3
SQLAlchemy                    1.4.32
stack-data                    0.2.0
statsmodels                   0.13.2
style                         1.1.0
sympy                         1.10.1
tables                        3.6.1
tabulate                      0.8.9
TBB                           0.2
tblib                         1.7.0
tenacity                      8.0.1
terminado                     0.13.1
testpath                      0.5.0
text-unidecode                1.3
textdistance                  4.2.1
threadpoolctl                 2.2.0
three-merge                   0.1.1
tifffile                      2021.7.2
tinycss                       0.4
tldextract                    3.2.0
toml                          0.10.2
tomli                         1.2.2
toolz                         0.11.2
tornado                       6.1
tqdm                          4.64.0
traitlets                     5.1.1
Twisted                       22.2.0
typed-ast                     1.4.3
typing_extensions             4.1.1
ujson                         5.1.0
Unidecode                     1.2.0
update                        0.0.1
urllib3                       1.26.9
w3lib                         1.21.0
watchdog                      2.1.6
wcwidth                       0.2.5
webencodings                  0.5.1
websocket-client              0.58.0
Werkzeug                      2.0.3
whatshap                      1.6
wheel                         0.37.1
widgetsnbextension            3.5.2
wrapt                         1.12.1
wurlitzer                     3.0.2
xarray                        0.20.1
xlrd                          2.0.1
XlsxWriter                    3.0.3
xopen                         1.6.0
yapf                          0.31.0
yarl                          1.6.3
zict                          2.0.0
zipp                          3.7.0
zope.interface                5.4.0
```

**How to prevent the error: `Don't know how to allocate array with layout 'A`'  from `numba`?**

Comment: I am not familiar with alphapeel, but it does not mention any kind of support for numba. If you try to give an unfamiliar module to numba, it wont be able to compile it, so I do not think that what you are trying to do is possible. If you share your code, I might be able to help further

Comment: @Rafnus I'm not sure if I understand what you say. Alphapeel itself uses numba see https://github.com/AlphaGenes/AlphaPeel/blob/master/src/tinypeel/Peeling/Peeling.py for example. Peeling.py imports functions from `numba` and `numba.experimental` I have only very limited knowledge about jit programming so I definitly could not do this stuff myself.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this error with the following setup:

1. Create `venv` for python3.7
2. Download Alphapeel repository from [here](https://github.com/AlphaGenes/AlphaPeel)
3. Extract AlphaPeel-master and extract wheel-file from AlphaPeel.zip
4. Install AlphaPeel-1.1.x using the wheel file
5. Run AlphaPeel in commandline
6. An error appears stating that `mportError: cannot import name 'jitclass' from 'numba' (/home/oem/.venvs/my-venv-name/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/__init__.py)`
7. This can be fixed editing the file in conflict, using some editor, e.g. `nano`, to remove the function `jitclass` from the line `from numba import ...`
8. Add a new line with `from numba.experimental import jitclass`
9. Save the file and repeat for each file in conflict
10. Run Alphapeel

PS: Despite stating that the tools from Alphagenes can read plink files the package `alphaplinkpython` did not work on my setup. So better stick to the file format presented in the docs.